pdf. documents downloaded with python won't open
I used the following code to download multiple pdfs from a public site according to their id numbers, which are listed in an excel file. At first it works, but the files won't open using Adobe Reader, Chrome or Edge.
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Disable insecure certificate warnings
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

# Load the list of numbers from Excel
df = pd.read_excel('prospectos_numero.xlsx')
# Setting the header
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

# Click on each number in the list and download the corresponding document
for number in df['ID_num']:  # Replace 'numbers' with the name of the column in your Excel file
    url = f'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id={number}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    
    if response.status_code == 200 and response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/pdf':
        with open(f'{number}.pdf', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        print(f'Document {number} downloaded with success.')
    else:
        print(f'Failed to download {number}. Status code: {response.status_code}, Type of content: {response.headers["Content-Type"]}')

I tried using the base64 module, but the problem persists:
import base64
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

# Disable insecure certificate warnings
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

# Load the list of numbers from Excel
df = pd.read_excel('prospectos_numero.xlsx')
# Setting the header
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

# Click on each number in the list and download the corresponding document
for number in df['ID_num']:  # Replace 'ID_num' with the name of the column in your Excel file
    url = f'https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/downloadDocumento?id={number}'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    
    if 'Content-Disposition' in response.headers:
        print('Content-Disposition:', response.headers['Content-Disposition'])
        filename = response.headers['Content-Disposition'].split('filename=')[-1].strip('"')
        print('filename:', filename)
    
        content = base64.b64decode(response.content)
    
        if response.status_code == 200 and response.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/pdf':
            with open(f'{number}.pdf', 'wb') as file:
                file.write(response.content)
            print(f'Document {number} downloaded with success.')
        else:
            print(f'Failed to download {number}. Status code: {response.status_code}, Type of content: {response.headers["Content-Type"]}')

The error displayed by the Adobe Reader is: "Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open '1514.pdf' because this file type is not supported or it was damaged". Is the code corrupting the files in a way I can fix?

Both versions write response.content to the file.

Look at the files using a text editor, and see what's actually in them - my guess is that you're getting a HTML page with a PDF embedded in it (rather than the PDF data itself), or perhaps a HTML error page.  An actual PDF document will start with %PDF- followed by a version number.

@ScottHunter is correct, you are still writing response.content, not content in your base64 attempt. I've literally just ran your second code sample with 1514 hardcoded and file.write(content) and it saves the pdf content just fine (under the wrong name that you've also forgot to replace in open)

It was such a dumb mistake, thank you for your help!
